# 404 redirect work on current directory

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, .htaccess

**I decided to take the application of the rules of etiquette for the site**, `.htaccess`:

```
...
# Not found
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
...
```

It's working, but included `css` and `js` files are connecting on current directory, rather than relative to the root. Resulting in an error loading `css` and `js` files in subdirectories like `mysite.com/item/item/`.

---

**I can solve it like this**:

```
...
# Not found
ErrorDocument 404 mysite.com/error/404.html
...
```

It will work everywhere, but `url` is changing without chance to back door.

I want to get the same without change `url-address`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in the `header` of your `404.html`

```
<base href="/">
```

it works for all links and images included

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the reference to the css/js files inside your `404.html` file is absolute (and not relative).

Instead of using

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Or

```
<script src="../script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css">
```

You should use

```
<script src="/static/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
```

This `/` at the beginning of the link tells the browser to take the js/css files from the root of your domain (ie `http://DOMAIN/static/...`).